# How to make content of a widget scrollable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am creating a news website. I want to show categories of the website in widgets. I have used [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/) to achive this. I have two questions:

1. How can I make the widget's height fixed so that if more items are added to the widgets, a scrollbar appreas?
2. Is it possible that somehow I drag and drop one of the items in the widget to the columns and it becomes another widget?

If there's a better tutorial for this, please guid me towards that.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: 1. Set at fixed height with CSS and define it to be a scrollable. Something like `.widget-content {height: 60px; overflow-y: auto;}` 2. Just append the content and create the widget, and use the `makeSortable();` function :)

Comment: Could you please explain the 2nd one a little more? Thanks. Also if possible please answer this as an "answer" so I can mark it as an "answer" :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marco Johannesen:

1. Set at fixed height with CSS and define it to be a scrollable. Something like

`.widget-content {height: 60px; overflow-y: auto;}`

1. Just append the content and create the widget, and use the `makeSortable();` function :)